# ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry for key 'PRIMARY'

Tags: mysql

I am trying to add a new column to sql table -

```
ALTER TABLE table1 ADD COLUMN column1 VARCHAR(400) DEFAULT NULL;
```

But i am getting this error -

> ERROR 1062 (23000): Duplicate entry '82133627' for key 'PRIMARY'

In table1, we just have one primary key, and i ran the following command to see what's the result -

```
select * from table1 where <primary_key_field>='82133627';
```

Got 1 row in set

```
Primary key - primary_key_field int(11) NOT NULL
```

Also, i went thru some of the responses for similar errors where they suggested to check if the primary key has auto-increment. We just have one primary key in this table, and it does not have auto-increment.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Could you post the entire table definition?

Comment: @Renzo i just added the table definition in my main post here.

Answer (score 1):

solution -
need to lock table, and then after running the query unlock it

LOCK TABLES "table1" WRITE;

run the alter table command

then -
UNLOCK TABLES;